# how to convert video file to binary data using jQuery or Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I would like to transfer a video file to binary and store it in to sqlserver using jquery/Ajax. is it possible ? please guide me what should i do ?

Comment: DB actions using Jquery/Ajax is `not possible` ! You need to use a server side scripting language like `php`

Comment: @MageshKumaar i have tried with $v_dat= (binary)base64_encode($a); but i can't able to store it in sqlserver